# %40 keeps changing to %2540 when using SafeUrlAssembler

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm using safe-url-assembler in Angular 5.

I'm passing an email address into this assembler, which calls an API.

```
const endpoint = SafeUrlAssembler(environment.baseUrl.api)
  .template(ApiEndpoints.save)
  .param("emailID", email)
  .toString();
console.log(endpoint);
return this.http.put<any>(endpoint, httpOptions);
```

The problem is, when I pass the email into the URL, it comes out like "myemail%2540gmail.com" instead of "myemail%40gmail.com"

Has anyone solved this issue when using safe url assembler?

Comment: Replace the %40 with @.

Answer (score 1):

SafeUrlAssembler doesn't know that the string has already been "safed".  So, the already-escaped '@' ('%40') is read as the string to send.  Since '%' isn't safe, it's escaped to '%25'.

Instead of passing in the already-escaped email address ("myemail%40gmail.com"), pass in the regular email address with '@'. ("myemail@gmail.com")